# Cut variable path in java

Tags: java

For example I have this Path:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
```

Now I only want the Path but not the .exe like this:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip
```

How can I cut the last part out in dynamic paths with more or less directories or longer names at the end?

I tried playing around with `indexOf()` and `subString()` but I don't really get it to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using Java's path API:

```
Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe");
Path dir = file.getParent();
System.out.println(dir.toString());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

Comment: `Path dir = path.getParent();` it says that `path`. cannot be resolved

Comment: it should be `file.getParent()`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
String path = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe";
    String[] a = path.split(Pattern.quote(""));
    String newpath = "";
    for(int i = a.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if(a[i].compareTo("\\") != 0) {
            a[i] = "";

        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i].compareTo("") != 0) {
            newpath += a[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newpath);
```

Comment: @spi, you are right, it is way too overcomplicated - still, it is working. And since OP didn't say for which os, I think it is a valid answer. @Cedric, you could replace the \\ by `System.getProperty("file.separator")`  to make it system independent. And instead of `string.compareTo("")` (bad practice to create empty strings just for comparison) you may want to use something like `string.isEmpty()` or `equals`

Comment: @GameDroids thanks for the better suggestions, you're right

Comment: *"you're right"* It is possible to [edit] your own answer at any time.